# How to retrieve two aggregate columns from two different tables using joins?

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to retrieve sum of `Price Column` from `ITEMS TABLE` and join it with the `GOODS TABLE`. The problem is when I try to join these tables, the sum of quantity column `gQnty` in Goods Table gives me `84` instead of `14` for `DISH A`. Can anyone help me how to achieve this task where I can get exact quantity `gQnty` and price `iPrice` with a same query.

TABLE GOODS

```
gID | gName | gQnty
-------------------------
1     DISH A   10
2     DISH B   12
3     DISH A   4
```

TABLE ITEMS:

```
iID | gID | iItem | iPrice
--------------------------
1      1    Sugar    200
2      1    Milk     300
3      1    Fruits   100

4      2    Oil      200

5      3    Sugar    100
6      3    Milk     50
7      3    Fruits   40
```

My Query:

```
select g.gName, sum(g.gQnty)[gQnty], sum(i.iPrice)[iPrice]
from goods g join items i
on g.gID = i.gID
group by g.gName
```

Expected Result:

```
gName  | gQnty | iPrice
----------------------------
DISH A |  14   |  790  
DISH B |  12   |  100
```

Comment: Aggregate *then* `JOIN`. If you remove the aggregation, and return the results for your query, you'll quickly see why you are getting the results you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN WOULD BE A GOOD IDEA

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT gName, SUM(ITEMS.iPrice) AS iPrice
FROM GOODS
LEFT JOIN ITEMS
ON GOODS.gID = ITEMS.gID
GROUP BY gName 
)
SELECT gName, 
(SELECT SUM(gQnty) FROM GOODS WHERE GOODS.gName = A.gName GROUP BY gName ) AS gQnty,
iPrice
FROM A
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c438d674340e74e604c4cf0739bc1bb)

Comment: You're a life savior. Thank's a lot. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select g.gName, max(g.gQnty)[gQnty], sum(i.iPrice)[iPrice]
from goods g join items i
on g.gID = i.gID
group by g.gName
```

or even

```
select g.gName, avg(g.gQnty)[gQnty], sum(i.iPrice)[iPrice]
from goods g join items i
on g.gID = i.gID
group by g.gName
```

Comment: I have to use SUM function not MAX or AVG... Anyways I got an answer. Thank you for the help...